# Confusion converting decimal to hexadecimal in C++

Tags: c++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const string hexConversion = "0123456789ABCDEF";

int main() {
    int dec, remainder, quotient; 
    string hexNum = "";

    //input sequence
    cout << "Enter a decimal number: "; 
    cin >> dec; 
    quotient = dec; 

//conversion
    do {
        remainder = quotient % 16; 
        quotient /= 16; 
        hexNum.insert(0, hexConversion[remainder]); 
    } while (quotient != 0); 

    cout << "Your number in hex is " << hexNum << "."; 

}
```

I do not have a ton of experience coding, and would appreciate some insight as to what I'm doing wrong with this program! Here is the error being conveyed: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use one of overloads of [std::string::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/) but none of them accept int and char:

One of the matching your needs is accepting position, count and symbol, so call `hexNum.insert(0, 1, hexConverstion[remainder]);`

Answer (score 1):

If you were thinking of using the following function:

```
iterator insert( iterator pos, CharT ch );
```

you need to use:

```
hexNum.insert(hexNum.begin(), hexConverstion[remainder]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming because there is no such *overloaded* version of `string::insert` which takes `int` and `char` as arguments.

You can use this overloaded version:

```
 string& insert (size_t pos, size_t n, char c);
```

where `n = 1` in your case, as you want to add a character once only.

, or

```
iterator insert (iterator p, char c);
```

where `p = hexNum.begin()`

Checkout http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/insert/